# Function to obtain confidence interval given an estimate and its standard error?

Tags: r, function, confidence-interval

Given as estimate of a parameter (2.685) and its SE (0.319) from a regression model, I can compute the 95% Wald confidence interval as follows:

```
> c("2.5%" = 2.685 - 1.96*0.319, 
    "97.5%" = 2.685 + 1.96*0.319)
   2.5%   97.5% 
2.05976 3.31024
```

Is there an R function in an existing package on CRAN that can do this?

For sake of simplicity, let's assume that the parameter follows a normal distribution. I'm looking for the equivalent of [`CI()`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/Rmisc/html/CI.html) from `Rmisc`, but which takes the estimate and its SE as inputs instead of a vector.

Comment: What kind of distribution is this and wha are the parameters? You can then use the quantile function to calculate this

Comment: Assume it's a parameter from a paper and the estimate of the SE. I want to deduce the confidence interval from that. (I'm not sure how the `quantile` function would help here.) I found [this function](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/Rmisc/html/CI.html) in `Rmisc`, but it only takes vectors as input, while I'm concerned with point estimates only.

Comment: It looks like a normal distribution:  `qnorm(0.025, 2.685, 0.319)` gives `2.059771`, for example

Comment: @Pascal Yup, seems like it: `qnorm(0.975, 2.685, 0.319)` gives 3.310229, so works for the upper bound, too.

Comment: @RStudent was refering to this kind of functions (qbeta, qt, qnorm...), i.e. the quantile function associated to a specific distribution.

Comment: @Pascal It's in the context of estimates from regression models, so I suspect their distribution is under the assumption of normality...

Comment: Without the context, we cannot assume this. That is why @RStudent asked you to specify the distribution.

Comment: @Pascal I updated the original question stating the assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming normality, a one-liner solution would be:

```
> sapply(c(0.025, 0.975), function(x) qnorm(x, 2.685, 0.319))
[1] 2.059771 3.310229
```

Even if, as pointed out in the comments, it's much simpler to just:

```
> qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), 2.685, 0.319)
[1] 2.059771 3.310229
```

Comment: The one-liner solution is `qnorm(c(0.025, 0.975), 2.685, 0.319)`.